# Where can I download a full OS X 10.11.1 Public Beta installer?

Tags: macos, bootable-disk

I have a bootable OS X drive that I like to keep up to date, but with the replacement of "Install OS X El Capitan Public Beta" with "Install OS X El Capitan GM Candidate" in the App Store, I'm not sure where I can get the latest beta of 10.11.1. Does the app named GM Candidate now contain 10.11.1, or does 10.11.1 just not exist in fully-downloadable form?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, unless you have a paid developer account, the **only** way to get it is to download thru the app store.

I installed the GM version and the .1 update was offered to me as well. So you should get the GM and then the .1 update too.

Comment: So there's no way to download an installer application that comes preloaded with .1 in order to make a bootable drive?

Comment: not as yet unless you have a paid dev account. Even then I am not sure if they have an installer with the .1 installer integrated. Likely it is just an updater package. I would put the .1 installer on your El Cap install drive and just run it when the install has completed.